# Find closest "true" element in 2D boolean matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic, boolean, closest-points

I have a 2D matrix with boolean values, which is updated highly frequently. I want to choose a 2D index {x, y} within the matrix, and find the nearest element that is "true" in the table, without going through all the elements (the matrix is massive).

For example, if I have the matrix:

```
0000100
0100000
0000100
0100001
```

and I choose a coordinate `{x1, y1}` such as {4, 3}, I want returned the location of the closest "true" value, which in this case is {5, 3}. The distance between the elements is measured using the standard Pythagorean equation:

`distance = sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY)` where `distX = x1 - x` and `distY = y1 - y`.

I can go through all the elements in the matrix and keep a list of "true" values and select the one with the shortest distance result, but it's extremely inefficient. What algorithm can I use to reduce search time?

**Details:** The matrix size is 1920x1080, and around 25 queries will be made every frame. The entire matrix is updated every frame. I am trying to maintain a reasonable framerate, more than 7fps is enough.

Comment: Is matrix constant for many queries?

Comment: No, it is always being updated.

Comment: @MathuSumMut What's the maximum size of the matrix and total number of queries?

Comment: 1920x1080, processed at a reasonable framerate (ie. multiple times a second).

Comment: How many queries per one matrix - one? How many "true" values in a frame?

Comment: Let me add some details to the question

Comment: So the matrix remains fixed for about 25 queries, and then the *entire* matrix changes?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) I use multithreading to ease off the blow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If matrix is always being updated, then there is no need to build some auxillary structure like distance transform, Voronoy diagram etc.

You can just execute search like BFS (bread-first search) propagating from query point. The only difference from usual BFS is euclidean metrics. So you can generate `(u, v)` pairs ordered by `(u^2+v^2)` and check symmetric points shifted by `(+-u,+-v),(+-v,+-u)` combinations (four points when `u` or `v` is zero, eight points otherwise)

Comment: I am not seeing any other good approach too. But I don't think this will be fast enough if the number of queries are large and matrix is very large.

Comment: Euclidian distance is making this hard. Does it make sense to use Manhattan distance (distance = abs(distX) + abs(distY))?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tree data structure like a quad-tree (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to store all locations with value "true". In this way it should be possible to quickly iterate over all "true" values in the neighborhood of a given location. Furthermore, the tree can be updated in logarithmic time, if the value of a location changes.